# How to use sshpass for chained connection?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two customer's machines, `$gateway` and `$server`, the second one is only accessible from the first one. Public key auth is unavailable on both systems.
So, to execute some `$command` on the server I need to run `ssh $gateway ssh $server $command` and then type two passwords.
I can use `sshpass`, but it will handle only the first connection and I still need to enter the second password by hand.

How can I make completely noninteractive (without manually entering passwords) ssh access to the server?

The only way I see is to use tunnels, but they are hard to keep alive because of unstable internet connection.

Comment: What kind of an admin turns off public-key auth?.. (Maybe the servers have something else enabled, like gssapi?)

Comment: I know that someone will ask this =)

Comment: It's a very specific embedded system, maybe there is a way to enable keys but I don't want to touch anything except things I was explicitly allowed to touch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p $gateway" $server command
```

For example:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p albert@gateway.uibk.ac.at" root@hidden.uibk.ac.at command
```

This will use proxy the ssh connection to `$server` over another `ssh` command, without actually creating a tunnel. This makes sure that both ssh clients run locally, thereby using sshpass.

Comment: Great! Thank you! (to use with `sshpass` one just need to replace  `ssh` with `sshpass -p <corresponding_password> ssh`)

Comment: Ooops, I've found something like `ssh $gateway rsync $file $server:`. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: If $file is local, you could use rsync's -e option to use a different ssh command. Just check the manual using `man rsync`.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is placed on `$gateway`. Connection `localhost` <-> `$gateway` is terribly slow, so 'download the file to my laptop and then put it to the server' is not an option

Comment: `sshpass -p $password $gateway rsync -e "sshpass -p $password" $file $server:` ?